# Angular 2 No component factory found for BSMessageModal

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Im trying to show an alert on button click in angular 2 , but im getting

"No component factory found for BSMessageModal"

**tables.component.html**

```
<td><button (click)="onClick()">Issue</button></td>
```

**tables.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { Overlay, overlayConfigFactory } from 'angular2-modal';
import { Modal, BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';


@Component({
selector: 'app-tables',
templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./tables.component.scss'],
providers: [Modal]
})
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public modal: Modal) { }


 ngOnInit() { }
onClick() {
    this.modal.alert()
        .size('lg')
        .showClose(true)
        .title('A simple Alert style modal window')
        .body(`
            <h4>Alert is a classic (title/body/footer) 1 button modal window that 
        does not block.</h4>
        <b>Configuration:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>Non blocking (click anywhere outside to dismiss)</li>
            <li>Size large</li>
            <li>Dismissed with default keyboard key (ESC)</li>
            <li>Close wth button click</li>
            <li>HTML content</li>
        </ul>`)
    .open();
  }

}
```

**tables.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TablesComponent } from './tables.component';
import { TablesRoutingModule } from './tables-routing.module';
import { PageHeaderModule } from './../../shared';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';     //To display Tabs
import { ModalModule } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TablesRoutingModule,
        PageHeaderModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),  //To display Tabs
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ],
        declarations: [TablesComponent],
        entryComponents: [ BSMessageModal]   //Tried this !!! but no use!
    })
    export class TablesModule { }
```

I tried adding BSMessageModal in the entryComponents of my tables.module, but im not at all using this class.

**Full error trace:**

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for BSMessageModal. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?(…)
>
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for BSModalContainer. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?(…)

Comment: try adding TablesComponent to the entryComponents

Comment: I tried that too..it says TavlesComponent cannot be added to entryCompnt

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you got any solution? can you please post it if you found any solution?